# Floral 3D pattern more efficent way

Tags: sculpting, 3d-printing

I want to print a ball with flower pattern on it for my niece, like this cylinder I already did. This one, I made in sculting mode by hand, painting some flower patterns on in, but I think, there could be an more efficient way to do it, maybe by normal maps, or brush tamplates with patterns of flowers.

[image: Cylinder for candle casting mould]

Comment: you can use the Displace modifier for example. With Normal Map you won't be able to have real 3D relief

Comment: Do you know a good source for floral displaymant stamps?

Comment: not really, I guess you can find in a search engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways, the **Displace** modifier or the **Sculpt** mode.

You could find a black and white floral repeatable pattern, blur it a bit:

[image]

Then create your object, subdivide it a bit, give it a *Displace* modifier with the floral pattern as texture (If you've unwrapped your object you can choose *Coordinates > UV*), give it 2 *Subdivision Surface* modifiers, put them above and below the *Displace* modifier, and when you're glad, duplicate the object and apply the modifiers:

[image]

You could also sculpt on your object. In that case make sure your object is subdivided enough, then in *Sculpt* mode, use your pattern as texture image (go into the *Properties panel > Texture* to load your pattern) and set the *Mapping* to *Stencil* (left click to move the image, left click + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to rotate the image, left click + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to enlarge). This way you can be more precise:

[image]

[image]

If you struggle in any of those steps, please tell me.